# How to get autocomplete/search field as input in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Hai i have a intermediate table projects currently i have implemented it as checkboxes as input. I need to know how to use it as a search and select like a field which can search the projects and add multiple projects rather than selecting the checkbox.

```
f.input :projects, as: :check_boxes
```

I need to search and select multiple the projects from a list i should also be able to discard the selected one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `chosen` gem. Here is a tutorial explaining all the process. I expect that this can help you:

http://tech.eshaiju.in/blog/2014/01/01/autocomplete-using-chosen-in-rails/

Comment: Thanks that was easy :)